# Paypal IPN stopped sending back POST request to return url

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using django-paypal. I work with live API, not sandbox. Everything worked fine previously, but suddenly some time ago I stopped receiving any POST requests on my return URL (it's https://my_domain.tld/payment/success/ in example form).

The form I use:

```
<form class="paypal-form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@acc" id="id_business" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9999.00" id="id_amount" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name #XXX" id="id_item_name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://my_domain.tld/paypal/" id="id_notify_url" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://my_domain.tld/payment/cancel/" id="id_cancel_return" />
    <input name="return" type="hidden" value="https://my_domain.tld/payment/success/" id="id_return_url" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="Some custom data" id="id_custom" />
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="Inovice-ID-XXX" id="id_invoice" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" id="id_cmd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" id="id_charset" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" id="id_currency_code" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2" id="id_no_shipping" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" id="id_rm" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" alt="Pay Now with Paypal!">Pay Now with Paypal!</button>
</form>
```

`notify_url` is still getting its data and payment process is working fine. But when the user clicks "Return to merchant" after the payment on the PayPal site, he's just being sent to `return`, and request.POST is empty (looks like they use GET, not POST).

I haven't changed anything, but it's just stopped working.

Any suggestions?

**Upd**

I've added some logging yesterday and now I can see something weird.

I had 3 payments yesterday, at *14:41:40* they've sent POST to my success url, and at the *14:45:37* they have not (request.POST was empty), and then at *22:34:36* they've sent again.